# JavaScript function name conflict with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, prototype, conflicting-libraries

I have been working on some old jsp pages, and am trying to introduce jQuery to it. However, this is what I get when I start using jQuery on the page:

```
base.js:249 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
```

So obviously there is a conflict between our legacy base.js and jQuery. And here's the code snippet from base.js that caused the issue:

```
Object.prototype.each = function (f) {
    for (var n = 0; n < this.length; n++)    {
        f (this[n],n);     // This is line 249
    }
    return this;
};
```

The bad news is that I can't easily refactor this library out of the page because there are a few other JavaScript libraries using it for the page.

Is there anything I can do? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the minified version of jquery, try using the non-minified version.

Comment: find usages of that `each` method and make sure that the function was passed in as an argument

Comment: **Never, ever** add an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`. Even adding a non-enumerable one is questionable enough (you've just found out why), but an *enumerable* one will just break all kinds of things.

Comment: What exactly makes you think this is a conflict with jQuery?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry there is little I can do about the legacy code.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, that would mean I would have to modify a bunch of other libraries...

Comment: @Rein, nothing in particular. But the error appears whenever I try to add jQuery.

Comment: @RichardTheobald. I had tried both the min and the full versions. And I got the same thing.

Comment: @Hua: Raise it with your manager. As you integrate third-party libraries, this will bite you, and bite you, and bite you, and bite you. You can either fix it now, or die by a thousand cuts. In any case, at the very least, you can make it non-enumerable (unless you need to support IE8 and earlier). That would do a *lot* to mitigate the damage.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Sorry for my ignorance. But how can I make it non-enumerable? Is there something you can point me to?

Meanwhile, like you said, I will bring this up with my manager. The library was originally written in 2005. People today probably would know better!

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Hua: In ES5 they introduced the [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperty) function, which lets you create properties on objects that are non-enumerable. (In fact, they're non-enumerable by default.) `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "each", { value: function(f) { /*...*/ }});`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I have tried your code and don't get the error any longer. But I am not getting the result I want yet -- could be because of my code not working and I am still working on it.    
So I can use your code without breaking the library, suppose I don't have support IE8 and earlier?

Comment: @Hua: With that example, every object will still inherit the `each` function as they do with your original code, but `each` won't show up in `for-in` loops or `Object.keys`. So yes, unless you have something relying on that, it should work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks so much for your great help!! I wish I could mark yours as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Quick tip:**

This is just a **hack job**, to solve the issue:

```
Object.prototype.each = function (f) {
  for (var n = 0; n < this.length; n++) {
    if (typeof f == "function")
      f(this[n],n);     // This is line 249
    else
      console.log("You've got a problem here. The f is " + f);
  }
  return this;
};
```

The above code might work, as well as help you debug things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your solution, and I got the logging statement. So obviously it was calling the wrong function.

Comment: @Hua Could you find which calls what function and can you trace your issue to solve it?

Comment: The call is coming from jquery.dataTables.js (I've tried the min version with pretty much the same result). And here's the snippet:

`this.each(function() {
   // For each initialisation we want to give it a clean initialisation
   // object that can be bashed around
   var o = {};
   var oInit = len > 1 ? // optimisation for single table case
    _fnExtend( o, options, true ) :
    options;...`

Comment: @Hua Try using the full version of the table script.

Comment: Praveen Kumar: Thanks so much for your kind help! I managed to get things going using the full version of dataTables. However, I did have to make the change that @T.J. Crowder suggested:

`Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "each", { value: function(f) { /*...*/ }});`

I am assuming that such a change does not break the library.

Comment: @Hua Enjoy bro.. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for all the great help!!